# Polymer 1.0 - iron-list - selection

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Working with iron-list in dart Polymer 1.0. Try to implement a iron-list with selection of an item in the list. This works when the item is a String, but fails for a structured type.

When running the code below following printout is obtained.

```
>Contains : false
>Uncaught Unhandled exception:
>NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'shorttext'
>Receiver: Instance of 'JsObjectImpl'
```

A breakpoint inside (objText != null) list "objText->JavaScriptView->*proto*>get/set shorttext" Close, but suggesting something wrong with the binding.

The iron-list documentation mention something about putting an action on the item. The JavaScript example in the documentation has selection and uses a model.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list

> When true, tapping a row will select the item, placing its data model in the set of selected items retrievable via the selection property.
>
> Note that tapping focusable elements within the list item will not result in selection, since they are presumed to have their * own action.

Ok, anyone been into similar parts of dart-polymer 1.0? also just suggestions of how to work with a selection of an iron-list are welcome?

Html side:

```
 <iron-list id="id_list" items="{{listitem}}" as="item" selection-enabled>
   <template>
     <paper-item on-tap="tap_event">{{item.shorttext}}</paper-item>
   </template>
 </iron-list>
```

On Dart side:

```
class ItemText extends JsProxy {

  @reflectable
  String shorttext;
  ItemText(this.shorttext);
}

@PolymerRegister('list-demo')
class ListDemo extends PolymerElement {

  @property
  List<ItemText> listitem;

  @property
  int nrelements = 10;

  // Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  ListDemo.created() : super.created(){
    List<ItemText> l = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < nrelements; ++i){
      l.add(new ItemText('Name ' + i.toString()));
    }

    listitem = l;
    print('created : ${$['id_list'].selectionEnabled}');
    this.notifyPath('listitem', listitem);
  }

  @reflectable
  void tap_event(event, [_]) {

    IronList e = $['id_list'];
    Object objText = e.selectedItem;
    if (objText != null){
      print('Contains : ${listitem.contains(objText)}');
      print('The short text : ${objText.shorttext}');
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line

```
Object objText = e.selectedItem;
```

to

```
ItemText objText = convertToDart(e.selectedItem);
```

I guess this is a bug. Please report at https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart

I suggest not using the `.created()` constructor of Polymer elements. Use `attached()` or `ready()` instead.

Consider binding `selectedItem` to a property and run your code when the `selectedItem` value changes for this purpose, instead of the `on-tap` event.

```
`<iron-list ... selected-item="{{selectedItem}}">`
```

```
@Property(observer: 'selectedItemChanged') ItemText selectedItem;

@reflectable
void selectedItemChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
  // your code here
}
```

or

```
@property ItemText selectedItem;

@Observe('selectedItem')
void selectedItemChanged(ItemText newValue) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the very fast response. The suggested solution works. `convertToDart(e.selectedItem);` Makes the logic valid. Definitely the solution with the binding on selectedItem and @Observe method is better, here the newValue points at the correct item in the list and don't need any conversion. I could report the original problem as a bug or at least little more documentation on this. What do you suggest?

Comment: I'd report as bug and let the Polymer team decide how to proceed. If this answers your questions please mark it as answered with the checkmark below the upvote buttons, thanks!

Comment: You have got a point. I will report it, also in iron_list.dart there is get for selectedItem, so to me it should return a well defined dart Object.