# IronResponse calls an JsObjectImpl object, but I cant find class docs on it

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I was trying to parse the return of an IronAjax success handler and set the response to an instance of Map.  It seems to not like that.

My HTML Markup is:

```
<iron-ajax id="myAjaxId" auto
  url="http://localhost:12345/test_server/v1/daily"
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="handleResponse" on-error="handleError"></iron-ajax>
```

My Dart Code is:

```
void handleResponse(CustomEventWrapper cew, IronRequest ir){
  print("inside handleResponse");
  var data =  ir.response;       // <-- is type JsObjectImpl
  print("data");
  print(data);
  if (data == null) return;

  print ("About to set rows");
  List<Map> rows = data.containsKey("data") ? data["data"] : [];

  print("Variables are Set locally");

  $['myDatagrid'].render();
}

@reflectable
String camelToFormal (String input){
  String out;

  RegExp regex = new RegExp("([A-Z])");
  out = input[0].toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).replaceAllMapped(regex, (Match m) => " ${m[1]}");
  return out;
}
@reflectable
void handleError(CustomEventWrapper cew, IronRequest ir){
  print("____Error:____");
  print(ir.response);
}
```

The Error I get is:

```
type 'JsObjectImpl' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'other'.
```

I wasnt sure if I need to run convert over it, even though the return type set by IronAjax was *json*

So, since `ir.response` will either be set or null, i check if it is null first.   the `var data` line in `responseHandler` currently sets is, but i have also attempted to do something like:  `Map data = new Map.from(ir.response);` which fails as well.

Even though this is said to be handled as JSON, and is returning a jslint confirmed objected, it seems to have issues to convert it to a proper map instance.

According to Polymer IronRequest at: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax?active=iron-request
it says that responseis *, the parsed response body.  Am I mistaken as to how this is properly set up, or am I missing something?

Comment: You could try `Object` instead of map on the property and then use `convertToDart`. Not sure this results in a `Map` but worth a try I guess. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448961/polymer-1-0-iron-list-selection

Comment: What does: convertToDart do?  im trying to find docs on it

Comment: I don't know about docs. I think it's supposed to be an implementation detail that leaks occassionally. This probably needs a fix in the Dart IronAjax.

Comment: I did *convertToDart* and it works now! :)  `List<Map> rows = convertToDart(data["data"]) ?? [];  List<Map<String,String>> headers = rows[0].keys.map((m)=> {m:"${camelToFormal(m)}"}).toList();` does exactly as expected now.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Object instead of map on the property and then use `convertToDart`. Not sure this results in a Map but worth a try I guess. See also [Polymer 1.0 - iron-list - selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448961/polymer-1-0-iron-list-selection)

Comment: JsObjectImpl means you've got a wrapper around a JavaScript object. JS doesn't really have Maps, it just has Objects with keys. So convertToDart gives Dart map.